# Error: hd0 cannot get C/H/S values. grub rescue >

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, hard-drive, grubrescue

The power supply went out on our machine. We replaced the power supply.

Now when we boot up, all we get is a blank screen with a blinking cursor.

So we hold `shift` during boot up, and this error is displayed:

```
error: hd0 cannot get C/H/S values.
grub rescue>
```

I typed `ls` and I see `(hd0)` and `(fd0)`.

Is this installation screwed? Do we need to re-install? If so, can we use an Ubuntu Live disc to retrieve some of our files from the HDD's?

We are using: `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` (32bit)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Ubuntu Live-CD to access your files and you can also use it to repair your system:

1. Boot from the live cd
2. Install `lilo` (`sudo apt-get install lilo`)
3. If it is installed run: `sudo lilo -M /dev/XXX mbr` where `XXX` is your harddrive. In most cases `XXX` is `sda`. This installs a new master boot record (mbr) into the specified device. For details look at the [manpage of `lilo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lilo). When you enter the command you probably will see some warnings. You can safely ignore them. Several years ago `lilo` was the default boot manager and the warnings are related to that.

Now your system should boot without any problems.